# lagging in data.table R

Tags: r, data.table

Currently I have a utility function that `lags` things in `data.table` by group.  The function is simple:

```
panel_lag <- function(var, k) {
  if (k > 0) {
    # Bring past values forward k times
    return(c(rep(NA, k), head(var, -k)))
  } else {
    # Bring future values backward
    return(c(tail(var, k), rep(NA, -k)))
  }
}
```

I can then call this from a `data.table`:

```
x = data.table(a=1:10, 
               dte=sample(seq.Date(from=as.Date("2012-01-20"),
                                   to=as.Date("2012-01-30"), by=1),
                          10))
x[, L1_a:=panel_lag(a, 1)]  # This won't work correctly as `x` isn't keyed by date
setkey(x, dte)
x[, L1_a:=panel_lag(a, 1)]  # This will
```

This requires that I check inside `panel_lag` whether `x` is keyed. Is there a better way to do lagging? The tables tend to be large so they should really be keyed. I just do `setkey` before i lag. I would like to make sure I don't forget to key them. So I would like to know if there is a standard way people do this.

Comment: +1 What if `x` is keyed, but by another column (not `dte`) by accident?

Comment: @MatthewDowle: yes, this is exactly right .. it is another problem. i suspect i may have to have the function accept the name of the sorting column to check if that is the key

Comment: What if `dte` is the 3rd column of a 3 column key and the query does `by=` the 2nd column of the key? i.e. the key isn't used, but `x` is keyed and `dte` is in the key.

Comment: @MatthewDowle: yes.. this is the issue i'm trying to get at. currently i just set the key before running this but this isn't ideal. do you have suggestions for how to do this better?

Comment: It's a great question. I'm not sure how to do that better, than your way: passing the column name in to `panel_lag` and having a check inside that to check the caller is keyed by that column using the method in the other question. The environment that `j` is evaluated in is static, so you could save a variable in there (`doneCheck=TRUE`) to save checking and rechecking each time `panel_lag` is called for each group.

Comment: I guess the same could be asked of base R and other vector languages.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to ensure that you lag in order of some other column, you could use the `order` function:

```
x[order(dte),L1_a:=panel_lag(a,1)]
```

Though if you're doing a lot of things in date order it would make sense to key it that way.

Comment: thanks! but the tables tend to be large so key-ing is a good idea i think

Comment: I don't think I understand the question as edited now. What's wrong with using `setkey` before performing your function? Are you looking for a single line that will set the key and lag the variable?

Comment: no nothing wrong with that. that's what i do now. but i what if i forget to do that in the code? that's what i would like to make sure doesn't happen

Comment: You could do `setkey(x,dte)[,L1_a:=panel_lag(a,1)]` to key and lag in one line. I'd check with the package owner but I think it won't add overhead if `x` is already keyed by date.

Comment: Good question Blue. If `x` is already keyed by `dte`, `setkey(x,dte)` resorts the key (incurring cost) and if any rows change order it outputs `Already keyed by this key but had invalid row order, key rebuilt. If you didn't go under the hood please let datatable-help know so the root cause can be fixed.`.  Might be able to improve, or have an option to control that.