# How to create a time lag of a column of dates by another sorted column using the data.table package?

Tags: r, data.table

I currently have a data set that looks like:

```
data.table(Person=rep(LETTERS[1:3],c(3,4,3)),Time=c(3,5,10,1,3,6,15,2,5,9))

Person    Time
A            3
A            5    
A            10
B            1
B            3
B            6
B            15
C            2
C            5
C            9
```

Where each person has a corresponding time. Is there a way I can create a data set like:

```
Person    Time    Previous
A            3           5            
A            5           10    
A            10          10
B            1           3
B            3           6
B            6           15
B            15          15
C            2           5
C            5           9
C            9           5
D            5           5
```

Here, the dataset contains a Previous column that is essentially the lag of Time, but that it is done by the column Person. Hence, the last entry of someone in Person would be that person repeated.

I was wondering if there was an implementation for this in the data.table package. I can obviously use an apply function, but that would be slow. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383095/lagging-in-data-table-r

Comment: `DT[, lag:=c(tail(Time,-1),tail(Time,1)) ,by=Person]` would get you there using base functions inside the data.table call. Might not take particular advantage of the speed of data.table though.

Comment: here is a non data.table solution: `within(dat, Previous <- unlist(tapply(Time, Person, function(x) c(x[-1], x[length(x)]))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
R> DT[, Previous := c(Time[-1], Time[.N]), by=Person]
R> DT
    Person Time Previous
 1:      A    3        5
 2:      A    5       10
 3:      A   10       10
 4:      B    1        3
 5:      B    3        6
 6:      B    6       15
 7:      B   15       15
 8:      C    2        5
 9:      C    5        9
10:      C    9        9
```

Note that `.N` is a reserved word in the `data.table` package and is the number of rows in the groups, as segmented by the `by=` argument.